# push log directly into logstash in laravel

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk

i have found a solution on internet for push log into logstash and so i can watch them in kibana.

LogstashLogger:

```
class LogstashLogger {

    /**
     * @param array $config
     * @return LoggerInterface
     */
    public function __invoke(array $config): LoggerInterface
    {
        $handler = new SocketHandler("udp://{$config['host']}:{$config['port']}");
        $handler->setFormatter(new LogstashFormatter(config('app.name')));
        return new Logger('logstash.main', [$handler]);
    }

}
```

then i've added logstash channel

```
    'logstash' => [
        'driver' => 'custom',
        'via'    => \App\LogstashLogger::class,
        'host'   => env('LOGSTASH_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port'   => env('LOGSTASH_PORT', 4718),
    ],
```

and finally this is my logging in controller:

```
Log::channel('logstash')->debug('Logging to logstash');
```

and this is my `/etc/logstash/logstash.conf`:

```
input {
  udp {
    port => 4718
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    #index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    #user => "elastic"
    #password => "changeme"
  }
}
```

the problem is after calling my api i have no new index in elasticsearch so i cant see any data in my kibana

check indices in elasticsearch:
`curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'`
what is the solution and how i can debug this because it gave me no error

Comment: Logstash is typically TCP

Comment: @Matthew i tested TCP but not worked yet